# why to use accessor ( getters and setters)?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
  get foo(){//Why can't I use argument ^!^
    return 'getter';
  },
  set foo(value){
    console.log('setter: '+value);
  }
}

> obj.foo = 'bla'
setter: bla
>obj.foo
'getter'
```

So, I wanted to get the value of foo when it is set:

```
>obj.foo = 'bla'
setter: bla
>obj.foo
getter: bla
```

Using like this:

```
get foo(value){//but alas, I can't use any argument in getter
    return 'getter: '+value;
  }
```

Can we not get the value what we set after? I think I'm not understanding the usage of accessor, why do we use it specially for?

Comment: http://typicalprogrammer.com/doing-it-wrong-getters-and-setters/

Comment: Why would you pass an argument to a getter?

Comment: You may see what I wanted to get?

Comment: I mean I see the result you want; I'm saying the result doesn't make any sense. A getter is for accessing a specific property. Augmenting that property in the getter doesn't make sense. Is that the source of the issue?

Comment: NO, I'm little bit unclear with the usage get/set.....

Comment: read the article i posted, i'm too lazy to write an answer cloning existing publications

Comment: @vol7ron: That would cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: @sixfingeredman you're right.  Basically what I'm saying is in the setter you need to set the value to some property.  `this.value = value` then in the getter you can retrieve that property `return 'getter: ' + this.value`

Comment: @vol7ron, we must not... setter/getter can actually do http request, for example...

Comment: @vp_arth could you clarify?  I don't usually use getter/setter in this way (one of the reasons I didn't answer).

Comment: `in the setter you need to set the value to some property` - no, you need not. You can use setter how you want. for example store it to localstorage.. or to mysql database.

Comment: And more, if you just set it, and retrieve, w/o any side effects - you don't need setters/getters at all..

Comment: @vp_arth that's understandable, but by that logic, you don't need this object at all.  TMTOWTDI.  In this case, in order to access a value, a value must be set.  Where it's set is irrelevant to the question being asked.  Perhaps my use of *need* should be replaced with *could*

Comment: Last snippet in my answer might been interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

may be this would explain it more to you

```
var obj = {
 get foo(){
  console.log('getter'); 
  return this._foo;}, 
 set foo(v){
  console.log('setter'); 
  this._foo = v;
 }
}
```

while getting a value from the object passing a parameter wont mean anything.
while setting a value passing a parameter would mean and represent the value that needs to be set.

*Chrome console. AFter initializing the object*

```
obj.foo = "UI"
setter
"UI"

obj.foo
getter
"UI"
```

Comment: I added it when all you had was a block of code. Retracted after update.

Answer (score 0):

The getter is there simply to apply additional logic during all assignments to that property. As a `getter`, it doesn't make sense for it to receive a parameter, since there's no opportunity to pass one during the get operation.

If you want the `getter` and `setter` to use the current value of the property, what you need to do is store it somewhere that it is accessible to both getter and setter.

This could be on the same object, on a different object, or via a closure referenced variable.

```
var obj = {
  get foo(){
    return this.___foo___
  },
  set foo(value){
    this.___foo___ = value;
  }
}
```

So now the `get` and `set` are just a controlled access to the `___foo___` property.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: The underscores have no meaning. I just used that as a generic way to show that it's some arbitrary property that hopefully won't collide with any other. Could be 100 underscores if you want.

Comment: Oh! I was unknown of that.

Comment: @vp_arth: I have no idea what you're saying. `var obj = {}` is not at all the same. Unless you're missing the point. Yes, I'm not doing anything extra, but the OP apparently wants to, hence the question.

Comment: OP wants to know correct use cases: `why do we use it specially for?`

Answer (score 0):

You need setters/getters, when you need implement some non-standart logic for property.
For example, next object accumulate all assignments:

```
var obj = {
  _a:0,
  get a(){ return this._a;},
  set a(value){this._a+=value;}
}

obj.a = 5;
obj.a = 7;
obj.a
12
```

Also this useful, when you want to write some proxy object,
for example getter resolves data from remote server, and setter post your data to it.

If you need simple property, just use

```
{a:0}
```

instead of

```
{_a:0,get a(){return this._a;},set a(v){this._a=v;}}
```

---

Other snippet, with js 'privates':

```
function Obj(key) {
  var private = 0;
  var authorized = false;
  return {
    set token(v) {authorized = (v===key);},
    set data(v) {if(authorized) private = v;}
    get data() {return authorized?private:undefined;}
  }
}
obj = new Obj('pass');
obj.data = 5; // no effect
obj.token = 'pass';
obj.data = 'Data'; //Now works!
///...
```

Comment: Almost right. You implement your object access using getters and setters **in case** you ever want to associate additional logic with the setting/retrieval of a property. This might include abstraction (see decorator pattern) access control and side effects.